# [java ]regex to set minimum string(letters,hyphens,spaces,single quotes) length with each individual token allowed only preset times

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

The problem is I have to make sure the regex matches 4 or more characters which include:

- Letters (0 or more times)
- Single quote(0 or 1 time)
- Spaces(0 or 1 time)
- Hyphens (0 or more times).

I tried this regex to set minimum length

```
[a-zA-Z '-]{4,}?
```

but I can't seem to able to put the individual conditions.

Should I do the individual requirements and minimum character length limit on separate regexes?

Answer (score 0):

When you require something *0 or more times*, that is no restriction, you need not treat these in any specific way and using `^[a-zA-Z '-]{4,}$` would do for the "letters(0 or more times)" and "hyphens (0 or more times)" conditions.

The only problem to solve is the "0 or 1 time" conditions. Adding lookarounds would indeed help:

```java
Boolean isValid = text.matches("(?!(?:[^']*'){2})(?!(?:[^ ]* ){2})[a-zA-Z '-]{4,}");
```

This regex matches a full string consisting of letters, spaces, single quotes or hyphens with no two (or more) occurrences of a `'` and space chars. Namely,

- `(?!(?:[^']*'){2})` - a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are two (`{2}`) consecutive occurrences of any chars other than `'` char followed with a `'` char.
- `(?!(?:[^ ]* ){2})` - same but restricting the space char.